# Mongo $set removing other fields in object on update

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a mongo statement for adding and updating values into an object within my document.

Here is my current statement. field and value changes depending what is getting passed in:

```
 db.collection.update(id, {
   $set: {
     analysis : {[field]: value}
    }
  });
```

Here is an example of what a document could look like(there are potentially 20+ fields in analysis)

```
{
 _id
 analysis:{
  interest_rate: 22
  sales_cost: 4000
  value: 300
 }
}
```

The problem is that every time I update the object all fields are removed except the the field I updated.

so if

> field = interest_rate

and the new

> value = 33

my document would end up looking like this and all the other fields in analysis would be removed:

```
 {
   _id
   analysis:{
    interest_rate: 33
   }
  }
```

Is there a way to update fields within an object like this to keep the code simple or will I have to write out update statements for each individual field?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to build the path when you're trying to update nested field. Try:

```
let fieldPath = 'analysis.' + field; // for instance "analysis.interest_rate"

db.collection.update(id, {
    $set: {
        fieldPath: value
    }
});
```

Otherwise you're just replacing existing `analysis` object.

Comment: this does NOT work correctly... other fields are missing from doc.

Comment: just kidding, this actually does work. I thought the fields were not coming through on the update, but it turned out the fields were never there in the first place!